# Regex to Find and Replace url does not work or how to make it work

Tags: regex, wordpress, url, replace

Using [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) here are the inputs:

Regular Expression: `/category/*`

Replacement String: `/experiment/$0`

Target String: `http://google.co.in/blah_blah_blah/domainname.com/category/wp/`

Final String:`http://google.co.in/blah_blah_blah/domainname.com/experiment//category/wp/`

#### Expected Url

`http://google.co.in/blah_blah_blah/domainname.com/experiment/wp/`

How do i get the expected URL , is there something wrong in my regex?

Comment: Why don't you just substitute `/category/` by `/experiment/`?

Comment: @m0skit0 well anything can be present after `category/` that makes the  point of using `*`

Comment: You need the regular expression `category` without the slashes.

Comment: I understood that, but Occam's Razor: why search for a complicated solution while a simpler one does the job? My suggestion is still valid with what you're telling and is simpler. By replacing as I said, you still get what's after the slash since that part of the string is not modified.

Comment: @kuh-chan that won't work if the url after `/category/` contains the letter `category`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try regex:

```
/category/(.*)
```

In regex `.` is the wildcard and `*` is a "0 or more" qualifier. Therefore, Matching 0 or more (`*`) characters (`.`) after the forward slash should be expressed as `.*`

replacement:

```
/experiment/$1
```

$0 is a "pseudo group" that holds the entire match, i.e. "/category/...". You need to use parentheses to define other groups so that you can reference these groups in the replacement pattern, hence the `(.*)` part in the regex.

Comment: @Penchi could you add some explanation as to why it did not work earlier?(i.e. in my code)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the regex:

`/category/([^/]+)`

That will match everything up to the next slash. Notice I have also wrapped it in parentheses to `capture` it. Alternatively, if you just want EVERYTHING after `/category/` use:

`/category/(.*)`

You then need to change your replacement to:

`/experiment/$1`

`$1` is the first match.

this results in:

`http://google.co.in/blah_blah_blah/domainname.com/experiment/wp/`